# mysql time difference on different row

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

and I need to get the time difference for the day between them. Is there an easy way to do this without using TEMP TABLE?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select timediff(min(time_out), min(time_in)) as time_diff
from your_table
group by emp_id, `date`
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need an aggregation function over `time_out` and `time_in`?  `MIN()` will do the trick.  So much simpler than my answer!  +1

Comment: Thanks it works.. just one last question, whats the purpose of two groupings?

Comment: If you group by `emp_id` and `date` then you have can access `time_in` and `time_out` for every user and and date seperately. You would not need to group if you add a `where` clause specifying a unique `emp_id` and `date`

Comment: @eggyal: Thanks for the edit. Especially in MySQL an aggregate function would not be needed but in other SQL engines. But for compatibility your edit is the right choice.

Comment: @eggyal: Of course. You are right. There are 2 records per user and date. I meant that you don't need an aggregate function in MySQL if you have only 1 record in a group. Then you can do something like `select * from t group by something`. Thanks for correcting me.